# Best ways to evaluate randomness of a shuffled list

Tags: c++, c, list, random, shuffle

I'm trying to qualify the randomness of some shuffled list. Given a list of distinct integers, I want to shuffle it with different random generators or methods and evaluate the quality of the resulting shuffling.

For now, I tried to do some kind of dice experiment. Given a list of `input_size`, I select some bucket in the list to be the "observed" one and then I shuffle the initial list `num_runs * input_size` (always starting with a fresh copy). I then look the frequencies of the elements that fell in the observed bucket. I then report the result on some plot. You can observe the results bellow for three different methods (line plots of the frequencies, I tried histogramms but it would look bad).

[The dice experiment over three methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtceW.png)

Reporting plots only is not formal enough, I would like to report some numbers. What are the best ways to do it (or used in academic publications).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests

Comment: ... or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestU01

Answer (score 3):

Quantifying randomness isn't trivial.
You generate a huge amount of random numbers and then test if they have the properties exhibited from true random numbers. There are tons of properties you can test for, e.g., a bits should occure with a 50% probability.

There are a randomness test suites that combine a bunch of these tests and try to find statistical flaws in the pseudo random numbers.

[PractRand](http://pracrand.sourceforge.net/) is to my knowledge currently   the most sophisticated randomness test suite.

I'd suggest you write a program that uses your method to repeatedly shuffle an array of e.g. `[0..255]` and write the raw bytes to stdout. (so the output is a pseudo random bit stream) Then you can pipe that into PractRand and it will quit once it finds statistical flaws. `./a.out | ./PractRand stdin`.

[TestU01](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestU01)'s "Big Crush" is also a pretty good test suite, but it takes a very long time to run, and from my experiance PractRand finds more statistical flaws.

I suggest not to use the [Diehard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests) or the newer [Dieharder](https://webhome.phy.duke.edu/%7Ergb/General/dieharder.php) test suites, because they aren't as powerful and have [false positives](https://youtu.be/zOAErJYH0bw), even when using CSPRNGs or true random number generators.